# 24 hour ranges intersection logic

Tags: c, algorithm

I have schedules which can go from 21:00 to 04:00.
Mostly these schedules will be such that they might pass the 00:00 hour mark.
Now i also have to add normal schedules spanning from 00:00 to 23:59.
I would like to calculate an intersection for the same.
currently i am using

```
if(((mytime1.start_time <= mytime2.end_time) && (mytime2.start_time <= mytime1.end_time))).
```

I still don't have a valid fool proof logic for the intersection when the trans day schedules are taken into account please help.

Comment: Please provide an example on what you want to do with the intervals.

Comment: There should not be two overlapping intervals say `Two intervals 21:00 to 04:00 and 08:00 to 10:00 `should show as not intersecting while any of the `20:00 to 22:00 or 03:00 to 05:00` or even a completely overlapped schedule should show a conflict.In short there should not be any intersecting ranges.

Comment: Before you compare, simply add 24 to `mytime2.start_time` and `mytime1.end_time` if either is less than 12. This will work as long as each schedule is **never** longer than 24hrs.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist 11:00 - 01:00 including mid-day becomes 35:00 - 25:00 and does not test as intersection 13:00-14:00

Comment: **11:00 - 01:00 becomes 11:00 - 25:00**. ONLY `mytime1.end_time` and `mytime2.start_time` need to be modified before comparision if they are less than 12. Do NOT modify `mytime1.start_time` or `mytime2.end_time`. I hope you are getting the logic.

Comment: Thnx it has worked.I wrote the code and then tested it that what it took for the delay.@TheCodeArtist

Comment: @TheCodeArtist: Please enter answers as answers, not as comments to the question. And what actual comparisons do you suggest evaluating? How do they handle 14-16 and 13-1?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes you are right, there are several corner-cases with my faulty approach which will NOT work for the entire 24hr range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool DoIntervalsOverlap(int s0, int e0, int s1, int e1)
{
    return s0 - e0 <= (unsigned int) s0 - e1 || s1 - e1 <= (unsigned int) s1 - e0;
}
```

First, note that, in essence, all of the arithmetic is unsigned. In `s0 - e0 <= (unsigned int) s0 - e1`, `e1` is converted to `unsigned int` to match `s0`, and `s0 - e0` is converted to `unsigned int` to match `(unsigned int) s0 - e1`. Below, I assume all arithmetic is unsigned.

In retrospect, I wish I had written the terms in reverse order. Let’s fix that now. `s0 - e0 <= s0 - e1` is equivalent to `e0 - s0 >= e1 - s0`. (This is true even in unsigned arithmetic.) Now we can think of `e0 - s0` and `e1 - s0` as the times *e0* and *e1* translated to a reference frame in which *s0* is at the origin. In this frame, any times that are earlier in the day than the original *s0* have been wrapped to large positive numbers. So, the wrapping around midnight is gone. We have only non-negative times measured from *s0*. Then we see that `e0 - s0 >= e1 - s0` is asking “Is *e1*, measured from *s0*, less than or equal to *e0*?” That question is equivalent to ”Is *e1* inside [*s0*, *e0*]?”

Thus, the two conditions ask “Is *e1* inside [*s0*, *e0*] or is *e0* inside [*s1*, *e1*]?” If either interval ends inside the other, the intervals overlap. If neither ends inside the other, they do not overlap.

Comment: `bool` is a C++ type. This question is tagged `C`.

Comment: @anthropomorphic: `bool` is in C 1999 and later, when `<stdbool.h>` is included.

Comment: I'll check that out .Test it and tell.

Comment: Can you please be some more clear of the nice logic.I dont seem to get it though it works.

Comment: @dev-null_to_dev_full: I replaced the previous text with a new explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider each instant of time in the first interval in order. If none of these instants coincides with the start of the second interval then the two intervals do not intersect, unless the intervals were already intersecting from the start, in which case the first instant in the first interval will occur in a similar pass along the second interval. So if the starts and ends are (l1, r1) for the first interval and (l2, r2) for the second, we can check by looking to see if l1 is included in the range [l2, r2] and if l2 is included in the range [l1, r1]. If lx is numerically no larger than rx then this is the simple check to see if e.g. (l1 >= l2) && (l1 <= r2). If lx is larger than rx then it is a wraparound interval and you could check if (l2 >= l1) || (l2 <= r1).